# Make javascript function with callback/promise implementation to always return a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to have an async authentication handler which can have an implementation with a callback or promises. The scope is to wrap this function in order to always return a promise, so I can use it further callback/promise agnostic.

I would be most grateful if someone could provide some help with these scenarios, one of the examples is real life.

What if the function is something like :

```
function getData(id, callback) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  apiCall('/path/to/id', function (err, data) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
    //do something with data
    deferred.resolve(processedData);
  }
  deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

and I want to use the .fromCallback in this manner

```
function myProcessedDataFunction(id) {
  return Promise.fromCallback(function (callback) {
    return getData(id, callback);
  }, {multiArgs: true});
}
```

Will this work ? Will myProcessedDataFunction return a correct promise ?

A real world example is:

I have an authentication handler which might or might not be implemented with a callback function, and at the same time could be implemented using promises; or it might return a true/false value;

```
function authHandlerImplementation1(username, password) { 
  return (username === 'validUsername' && password === 'validPassword');
}

function authHandlerImplementation2(username, password, callback) {
  apiCall('/path/to/authorization', function (err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, result);
  });
}

function authHandlerImplementation3(username, password) {
  return new Promise(function (reject, resolve) {
    apiCall('/path/to/authorization', function (err, result) { 
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resove(result);
    });
  });
}

function authHandlerImplementation4(username, password, callback) { 
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  apiCall('/path/to/id', function (err, data) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(new Error(err));
    //do something with data
    deferred.resolve(processedData);
  }
  deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I will try a bluebird implementation for 5th one.

```
function authHandlerImplementation5(username, password, callback) { 
  return apiCall('/path/to/id', callback).asCallback(callback); // I hope this is the right way to do it (correct me if I'm wrong, please)
}
```

and my checkAuth function uses the authHandler Implementation and wants to be callback/promise agnostic.

```
function checkAuth(username, password) { 
  var self = this;
  return Promise.fromCallback(function(callback) { 
    return self.authHandler(username, password, callback); 
  }, {multiArgs: true});
}
```

In case the authHandlerImplementation does not use callbacks (just returns a value) (implementation1), the checkAuth hangs, nothing happens, my tests fail.

Is there any Bluebird method that can wrap any kind of authHandler Implementation into a promise (be it simple return, callback or promise implementation)?

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to mix promise and callback style functions thos way. I think it's much better to stick with one, and convert the functions to the preferred one on entry. The reason is that it's impossible to decide if a function uses callbacks or not.
What should happen if `authHandler` is synchronous and returns an immediate undefined? And by the way, bluebird `fromCallback` will only work with callback style functions.

Comment: I highly recommend you choose either callbacks or promises (hopefully the latter), not both. Supporting both is messy here, and at the call site. A guy where I work wrote quite a lot of code that supported both methods, and it turned into maintenance hell. Replacing it with a just-promises implementation halved the LoC and made the code a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I understand your position and I agree with sticking to one of the variants for simplicity. On the other side, I want to give the end user the freedom to use either. Not forcing an implementation style is what I'm trying to achieve with this. 

@TamasHegedus One of the underlying questions is as you stated: How can you figure out if a function uses a callback or a promise or neither? 
I found out now that ```fromCallback``` is ```only``` for functions implemented with a callback. I thought it supported promise style functions as well.

If there is any way to do this, please do advise!

Comment: "I want to give the end user the freedom to use either." - Write a pure "node-style callback"-based implementation. If that's done, the end user—or yourself, for that matter—can choose to promisify it painlessly via Bluebird [in one line of code](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html).

Comment: @Tomalak I think it's the other way around. The end-user writes the implementation of the function (be it promise/callback style). The component which I'm trying to write wants to use the function, that the end-user writes, in a promised way. I hope that I'm making myself understood.. or could you provide a short example?

Comment: @Tomalak so, what you're suggesting is.. impose the node-callback style implementation to the end-user and behind the scenes I promisify the function.. am I getting this right?

Comment: @brainsearching Its possible to create a function that can call both promise returning and callback style functions, but adding immediate functions makes this impossible, as there is no way to distinguish a callback style async function and a sync function that returns undefined (or a callback style function which returns an immediate value too for whatever reason)

Answer (score 2):

No, Bluebird has no such utility. Supporting both callbacks and promises is nice if you provide them as an API, but not when you need to consume an API - distinguishing whether the method takes callbacks or returns promises or both is not possible from outside, and writing code that figures it out dynamically (on every call) might be possible but awkward.

Bluebird *does* have a utility that wraps function which might return, throw or return a promise, it's called [`Promise.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) (and there's also [`Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html) which immediately invokes it).

I would recommend to force your callers to use promises if they want to pass an asynchronous auth-handler. If they only have a callback-based one, they still can wrap it in [`Promise.promisify`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) themselves before making it available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some stuff around and I've managed to make it work. I will provide detailed information of the methods I've tried, below. The scenario is for a json-rpc 2.0 server implementation which receives an authHandler function implementation for checking the validity of the provided credentials in a request.

Update: 
Using Promise.method on the authHandler 
`var promisifiedAuthHandler = Promise.method(self.authHandler);` works for the synchronous implementation of the authHandler.
Fails for the callback implementation.

Using Promise.promisify on the authHandler wrapped in the Promise.method works for the callback implementation 
`var promisifiedAuthHandler = Promise.promisify(Promise.method(self.authHandler));`. 
Fails for the synchronous implementation.

Providing a callback for the authHandler (even if it does not use it in the implementation) works for all methods. It goes like this (writing for a general case, and this is part of a module written using [ES5-Class node module](https://github.com/pocesar/ES5-Class)):

```
function _checkAuth(req) {
  var self = this;
  var credentials = self._getCredentials(req);
  var promisifiedAuthHandler = Promise.method(self.authHandler); // for the sync implementation

  switch (authType) {
  // general case, let's say, there are several types
  // will just write one as an example.
  case Authorization.WHATEVERTYPE: 
    return promisifiedAuthHandler(credentials, function callback(err, result) {
      if (err) return Promise.reject(err);
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
  }
}
```

and the server.enableCookie/JWT/BasicAuth handler can be implemented in the three ways mentioned: sync/callback/promise; As follows:

```
server.enableCookieAuth(function (cookie) {
  return (cookie === validCookieValue);
});

server.enableCookieAuth(function (cookie, callback) { 
  apiCall('path/to/auth', function(err, result) { 
    // apiCall could have a promise implementation, as well, and could 
    // be used with .then/.catch, but this is not that important here, since we care 
    // about the handler implementation)
    if (err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, result); // can be returned
  }
});

server.enableCookieAuth(function (cookie) {
  // let's write the apiCall with promise handling, since we mentioned it above
  return apiCall('path/to/auth').then(function (result) {
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
});
```

Now, we can use our _checkAuth function internally using only promises, agnostic of the authHandler function implementation. As in:

```
handleHttp: function(req, res) {
  var self = this;
  // ...other processing
  self._checkAuth(req).then(function (result) {
    // check if the user is authed or not 
    if (result) {
      // further process the request
    } else { 
      // handle unauthorized request
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
     // handle internal server or api call (or whatever) error 
  });
}
```

The trick was to write our callback with a promise implementation. We always provide the authHandler a callback implementation, even if the authHandler does not use it. This way, we always make sure that the auth handler implementation returns a promise if it uses a callback style implementation.

All comments are welcomed and I would like to hear some opinions on this matter!

Thank you for your prompt responses!